# Facebook and Koala: no cover from graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm using the Koala gem with Ruby on Rails to pull in lots of data from Events I'm a host of. I've created the query in the Graph API Exporer:

```
Me?fields=picture.type(large),location,events.fields(name,location,end_time,privacy,updated_time,description,rsvp_status,venue,start_time,id,ticket_uri,picture.type(square),cover,owner,admins.fields(picture.type(square),name,location),attending.fields(picture.type(square),name,rsvp_status,first_name,last_name,email,location),maybe.fields(rsvp_status,picture.type(square),name,first_name,last_name,email,age_range,location))
```

Cover *should* show for events, it says so in the response from the Graph Explorer. But when I'm inspecting the incoming data with Rails Console, it's nowhere to be found. After some research I've found a year+ ago that there was a bug with Event covers not being accessible. I was wondering if this has been fixed finally or am I doing something wrong with my call.

Here's my code:

```
def generate_user_events
events = facebook { |fb| fb.graph_call(event_graph_call)}
events["events"]["data"].each do |event|
      @new_event = Event.where(fb_id: event["id"]).first_or_create(
        cover_url:      event["cover"]["source"],
        cover_url_x:    event["cover"]["offset_x"],
        cover_url_y:    event["cover"]["offset_y"]) 
end

 end
```

EDIT: I cleaned out extra code upon request.

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug in the FB console here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you make it shorter and more clear? What all this code has to do with cover?

Comment: @majioa When I use the Facebook Graph API the cover data shows correctly. (I have the correct privacy token, btw.) When my app tries to access the event information the cover information is never there.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel I cleared out a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: how do you, use the Facebook Graph API, on the site? if yes, the problem shell be in your rights, I believe. Please see fb permission page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/, i.e. when you have requested the oauth token, you haven't specified correct right.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly @majioa I do use the Facebook Graph API on the web app to show a list of events the current user is an admin of.

An API call is made and all the events, all the attendees, admins, etc connected to each event. I'd like to pull in the cover images for each event as well because that would improve the consistency between Facebook and my app.

I have the appropriate permissions for said action because I can reproduce the result in the Graph API Explorer... the Cover data is present. When the same call is made from my app, the Cover data is missing.

Comment: but you are using *koala* gem, it also requires the proper permission requested from FB when you get oauth token. And which permission set you have requested?

Comment: @majioa Forgive my ignorance, are you talking about the settings in omniauth.rb?

Comment: What's really strange is that I'm attempting to do the same thing with Friends' covers. I can pull in the data by stopping the program for each friend call with Binding.pry, and manually access the cover url. The moment I get my app to do the same it throws a Nil Class error

Comment: @majioa the scopes I am tapping into are: create_event, create_note, email, friends_checkins, friends_location, friends_photos, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_stream, rsvp_event, share_item, sms, status_update, user_about_me, user_activities, user_checkins, user_events, user_friends, user_hometown, user_location, user_photos, video_upload

Comment: I what to clarify something, Am I right that you have simulated the work of the required functionality in the FB console, and it works?

Comment: @majioa Yes, I have simulated access to this information in the console and it works. When my app tries to do the same it returns in a NilClass error.

To your point, since I can do it in the console and my app cannot, I tried looking for some kind of authentication problem. I didn't find anything out of the ordinary.

My repo is online here: https://github.com/josephdburdick/buoy.git

Comment: It seems that something wrong with the *koala* gem. Anyway, could you show your expection?

Comment: @majioa my expectation is the following...and this is coming from pry, stopping right AFTER I bring in each event.

[1] pry(#<User>)> event["cover"]
=> {"cover_id"=>"10101499775804316",
 "source"=>
  "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s720x720/1506554_10101499775804316_624564120_n.jpg",
 "offset_y"=>59,
 "offset_x"=>0}

As you can see, Pry was able to pull the data for the Event's cover information. My expectation would be that when I used my original submitted code event["cover"]["source"] it would return with the url of the cover image.

Comment: I see, but could you add the error trace, and dump of correct answer in the `pry` into your post?